# Windows 10 - Can't open Device Manager "This app has been blocked for your protection"

Tags: windows-10, uac

#### Problem

Running a new Windows 10 Enterprise machine with all updates (1803) and whenever I try to open the device manager (or other programs like it), I get a UAC pop-up dialog saying "This app has been blocked for your protection" with only a close button.

[image: uac warning]

When I click on the link "Show information about the publisher's certificate" nothing happens.

This issue occurs when logged in as an administrator type user or when logged in using the built-in Administrator account.  I am looking for the root cause of this issue and an appropriate fix (I already have a workaround -- below).  There are several similar questions on Super User, but they are either a) very old, or b) only suggest the work-around.

#### Current Workaround

Currently I run a cmd console as administrator and enter the program name as a command and it just works.  Besides being inconvenient, it leaves me wonder if something larger is broken here.

NOTE: I have another Windows 10 Enterprise machine I created 10 months ago with the same DVD, also updated (1803) and it does not exhibit this behavior.

#### Other approaches

- Disabling Windows "Smart Screen" as shown [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-app-has-been-blocked-your-protection-windows-10) does not work.
- Creating another user profile does not work.
- Disable defender (virus) scan has no effect.
- Changing the ownership of `mmc.exe` to myself instead of `TrustedInstaller` is a hack which shouldn't be necessary as the `Administrator` group already has read & execute access.

Comment: I have seen a video, perhaps it can help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDA1URdYRME

Comment: Sorry, but that video says to enable the built-in Administrator account and run the program from there.  As I mentioned, I'm already logged in as the built-in Administrator.

Comment: You’re right, the file isn’t signed directly but via catalog. SigCheck detects that for me though and reports the following security catalog: `C:\Windows\System32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\Microsoft-Windows-BusinessScanning-Feature-Package-admin~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1.cat` – Does this file exist on your device? What about others in this folder? There should be over 2000 files in there.

Comment: I was getting this error when I renamed `C:\Windows\System32\CatRoot2` trying to fix my issues with Windows Update. Renaming it back brought things back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a bit late but i just fixed the exact same issue you're having by disabling Admin Approval Mode and the built-in admin account viaw GPEdit security policies.

Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options. At the top is the admin account policy but scroll to the bottom and you'll see UAC policies. Disable Admin Approval Mode restart your pc and see if it fixes it.